# reading data from a randomaccessfile

Tags: java, io, randomaccessfile

Here is the function I have :

```
// Read a record from the specified RandomAccessFile
   public void read( RandomAccessFile file ) throws IOException    {
      account = file.readInt();
      byte b1[] = new byte[ 15 ];
      file.readFully( b1 );
      firstName = new String( b1, 0 );
      firstName = firstName.trim();
      byte b2[] = new byte[ 15 ];
      file.readFully( b2 );
      lastName = new String( b2, 0 );
      lastName = lastName.trim();
      balance = file.readDouble();
   }
```

I have to be able to read from a randomaccessfile for one of my exams and the code above is a bit confusing.

here is what I am guessing is happening, would appreciate it if you could correct me if I am wrong.

we take `file` in and `readInt` from the file and assign it to `account`. next I guess we create a new byte of size 15 and read the first name from the file into the byte and then assigned to `firstname`. now here is what I dont understand, what does `readFully` do? and how does the code above knows to move on to the next value for `lastName`.
So simply put,

```
byte b1[] = new byte[ 15 ];
      file.readFully( b1 );
      firstName = new String( b1, 0 );
      firstName = firstName.trim();
```

VS

```
      byte b2[] = new byte[ 15 ];
      file.readFully( b2 );
      lastName = new String( b2, 0 );
      lastName = lastName.trim();
      balance = file.readDouble();
```

Why doesnt it give the same value? are we guessing how long each value (firstname, lastname etc) is ?

Comment: did you read any of the javadocs for RandomAccessFile?

Comment: Yes I did but tbh I had to study a lot of different things so it gets a bit confusing so I was hoping someone could explain it in simple words

Answer (score 1):

As the api says:

Reads `b.length` bytes from this file into the byte  array, starting at the current file pointer. This method reads   repeatedly from the file until the requested number of bytes are  read.

```
    public void write(RandomAccessFile file) throws IOException {
    file.writeInt(account);
    byte b1[] = new byte[15];
    // set firstname to b1
    file.write(b1);
    byte b2[] = new byte[15];
    // set lastname to b2
    file.write(b2);
    double balance =123.1;
    file.writeDouble(balance);
}
```

if you generate the file exactly like that above,you read progress will be ok.

Comment: but is the above code reliable? what if a value is larger than 15 bytes? could you explain how exactly java knows what the next value is? if the record shows `1 name lastname 10.00`, how would the code above read it?

Comment: It depends on how the file is generated,If each record is stored as 4byte+15byte+15byte+8byte,they will be read correctly

Comment: ohh ok, that was the confusing part, so you have to take bytes into account to be able to locate a value correct?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a school/university exam, bear in mind that they know to have absurdities on purpose, to confuse you.

Considering a comment from the code you posted:

> Read a **record** from the specified RandomAccessFile

I'd bet that it is defined that the binary file you are reading from has data stored in records like this:

- account - 4B (size of int)
- first name - 15B
- last name - 15B
- balance - 8B

I also bet that it is supposed that the data is written correctly - meaning exactly in the above order and length. If it is not, e.g. there is a string instead of the integer, or the first name is bigger, it will probably result in error or misinterpreted data - that's why your snippets give different results.

It is a [binary file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) you are reading from anyway, if you want to read something out if it, you **must** now the exact format in which it was written. Otherwise it's like deciphering an alien letters.

As for the [RandomAccessFile.readFullyMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readFully%28byte%5b%5d%29):

> Reads b.length bytes from this file into the byte array, starting at the current file pointer. This method *reads repeatedly* from the file *until the requested number of bytes are read*. This method *blocks until* the *requested number of bytes are read, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown*.